# MSSQL Join Calculation

Tags: sql-server, join

i am searching for a solution in regards to joining and MSSQL.

I have two tables.

The first one the Basic Table:

```
ID, Name, Key
1, Test1, 1x11
2, Test2, 2x22
3, Test3, 3x33
```

The second is the table which I want to join to the Basic table:

```
Key, Action, create,         close,           duration
1x11,   1,  01/01/2021 06:00,01/01/2021 07:00,  1
1x11,   5,  01/01/2021 07:00,01/01/2021 10:00,  1
1x11,  10,  01/01/2021 10:00,0,                 0
2x22,   1,  01/01/2021 10:00,01/01/2021 11:00,  1
2x22,   5,  01/01/2021 11:00,01/01/2021 12:00,  1
2x22,   7,  01/01/2021 12:00,01/01/2021 13:00,  1
2x22,   5,  01/01/2021 13:00,01/01/2021 14:00,  1
2x22,  10,  01/01/2021 14:00,0,                 0
3x33,   1,  01/01/2021 10:00,01/01/2021 12:00,  2
3x33,  10,  01/01/2021 12:00,0,                 0
```

In this table the closedate was not given, so i had to use the following command to get the closedate (closedate is the next createdate):

```
 lead (create,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Key ORDER BY create) AS close
```

Now, my goal is to join the sum(of ActionNumber 5 per Key) to the  basic table

Can someone tell me how to do that? I am really frustrated.

Final Table:

```
ID, Name, Key, join(sum of 5)
1, Test1, 1x11,1
2, Test2, 2x22,2 (because there are two times one hour that means 2h)
3, Test3, 3x33,0
```

Thanks for helping. Christian

Comment: Which column do you want to sum? And do you need the other rows with Action<>5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two tables exist then this should be a simple aggregation.

```
SELECT
    B.ID,
    B.Name,
    B.Key,
    CountAction5 = SUM(CASE WHEN S.Action = 5 THEN Duration ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    BasicTable B
    INNER JOIN SecondTable S ON S.Key = B.Key
GROUP BY
    B.ID,
    B.Name,
    B.Key
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, all you need is to do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT [key], SUM(CASE WHEN Action = 5 THEN duration ELSE 0 END)
FROM t
GROUP BY [key]
```

where `t` is the second table.

Output:

```
key sum_of_5
-------------
1x11    1
2x22    2
3x33    0
```

To join back to the original table use a derived table:

```
SELECT [key], name, sum_of_5
FROM t1
JOIN (
    SELECT 
       [key]
       , SUM(CASE WHEN Action = 5 THEN duration ELSE 0 END)
    FROM t
    GROUP BY [key]
) t2 ON t1.[key] = t2.[key]
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/40492/1)